# Solr Dismax weird behavior

Tags: solr, lucene

A weird behavior with respect to "defType". Any clues will be appreciated.

Query 1: http://localhost:8085/solr/select/?q=abc&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&defType=dismax [defType with capital T -- does not fetch results]

Query 2: http://localhost:8085/solr/select/?q=abc&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&deftype=dismax [defType with small T -- perfect, results returned]

In the above queries I have removed the boosting part because of which I am using dismax. And also while placing boosting stuff it is the other way round, deftype returns with capital T and does not return with small T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remarking where the problem is: `defType=dismax` is fine, while `deftype=dismax` doesn't work as you expect because `deftype` is not a valid Solr parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The `deftype` parameter is unknown to Solr, so when you use this parameter, Solr actually uses the default query parser, which searchs on the default search field (see schema.xml) and doesn't support boosts out of the box.

You should turn `debugQuery` on to see how your query is parsed with dixmax and how it differs from the query generated with Solr default query parser.